# Code Completion Error in Camel blueprint.xml

Tags: xml, eclipse, apache-camel

Editing camel blueprint.xml in Eclipse (CodeReady 12.17) and code complete ctrl-space is throwing an error see screen shot.

[image]

What can I do to repair?

Comment: can u run mvn clean eclipse:eclipse     and then refresh the workspace.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using CodeReady 12.14 and fuse-karaf 7.6 they both run on jdk 8 and the libraries all synch up.  Since I was running CodeReady on 12.19 on jdk 11, and only added the jre 8 with project java 8 compliance I got the combined parsing somehow and the camel 2.x from one and the camel 3.x from the other hence two opposite error messages.  Staying with the older versions that matched dev and runtime solve the problem.  Will worry about finding another synched setup later.